# Number of congruences for given polyhedron

Tags: abstract-algebra, polyhedra, dihedral-groups

First: I don't know if I'm using the terminology in the right way, since I translated this.

In my textbook, a congruence is a transformation that keeps all distances equal, and it is proved that this is either a translation, rotation or reflection by a line through the origin.

> Prove that there are $48$ congruences of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that map a given cube into itself. Do these form a group? An abelian group?

Well, I tried to solve as follows: there are four diagonals for the cube, which may be mirrored or might stay equal, giving $4!=24$ different congruences. Then, just like in a dihedral group, we can, for all of these congruences, invert the cube, so that other points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are mirrored by the plane $z=0$, where $(x,y,z)$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Thus we find $24\cdot2=48$ congruences.

It is easy to see that this is a group: we have the identity image and can easily invert all rotations and reflections. Associativity also follows easily. Commutativity is not true, because this is not even the case for a dihedral group in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I think this answer is allright, but then the follow up question:

> How many congruences of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that map a given regular polyhedron with $20$ sides into itself?

I really have no idea where to start. Wikipedia tells me that I'm looking for a [regular icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron). As I interpret this, there should be $120$ such congruences. But I don't see how I should derive this and how I would know, without the use of internet, what a  regular polyhedron with $20$ sides would look like. Any help is much appreciated!

**N.B.**: this question appears in the first chapter of a group theory syllabus/textbook, including definitions, examples and basic proofs about groups, so the answer should be elementary.

Comment: A cube has 8 vertices, each vertex connect to 3 adjacent neighbors so symmetry group has 48 = 8 x 3 x 2 (2 from reflection) elements. An icosahedron has 12 vertices, each vertex connect to 5 adjacent neighbors, so symmetry group has 120 = 12 x 5 x 2 elements.

Comment: I don't really see why this method works. Can you explain this a little bit more? I am really new to this subject and I can't find a good explanation in my book or on internet. Also, how should I know that when I am talking about a regular polyhedron with $20$ sides, that this figure has $12$ vertices each with 5 adjacent neighbours?

Comment: By the way I see why your method works. Rotating the vertices towards the other vertices is the only way rotating maps the solid into itself.

However, I still don't see how I should know how many vertices and adjacent sides we have, given only a regular polyhedron with $20$ sides. Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: There are only 9 [regular polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polyhedron), the 5 Platonic solids (tetrahedron, cube, octahedron, icosahedron and dodecahedron) and 4 more regular star polyhedron. The star one self intersect, so they are not the polyhedron we ordinary refer to. Among the five common one, there is only one, the icosahedron, which have 20 faces.

Comment: That explains a lot, thanks! :) I wasn't aware of this fact